# Use libuv to act on a module poll

Tags: polling, libuv, reactphp

I wrote a Linux module with a .poll and want to use libuv to read the signal.

This is in the poll function called by file_operations

```
unsigned int mask = 0;
poll_wait (file, &read_waitq, wait ); 
if (convert_finish_flag)
    mask |= POLLIN | POLLRDNORM;
return mask;
```

Currently I am using a simple epoll user client to catch the signal, which works fine. But code wise it would be nicer to use libuv. Because I also use ReactPHP with EventLoops.

These are the most relevant lines in the user client.

```
fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
ev.events  = ( EPOLLIN | EPOLLET );
epoll_ctl( epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev )
epoll_wait( epoll_fd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1 );
```

I tried several examples from the [php_uv](https://github.com/amphp/ext-uv) project like fs_poll.php, calling `touch /dev/my_driver` does work. But it does not respond to a poll from the module.

Can somebody confirm this could work?
Seems like it should be possible, but it's difficult for me to debug libuv/php-uv or am I missing something else?